# How to retrieve integer value from JSON data in Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt

How can I retrieve the integer value from the `QJsonValue` object? Suppose that I have the following JSON data:

```
    {
        "res": 1,
        "message": "Common error"
    }
```

I need to extract the "res" value from this data, so I've tried to use the following code:

```
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(some_json_data.toUtf8());
QJsonObject root_object = d.object();
QJsonValue res = root_object.value("res");
```

But I've found that `QJsonValue` class doesn't have a member function toInt or something like this (there's `toDouble`, `toString`, etc only). What can I do in such a situation? What is the best way to extract integer values via `QjsonValue` class?

Comment: This is discussed here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24013/

Comment: so it comes down to: use a different json library, or change qt :)

Comment: If you want `int`, what's the problem with just using `QJsonValue::toDouble()` and casting to `int`? If you wanted a 64 bit integer, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

(tl;dr: a one-liner solution at the end of answer.)

First a comprehensive way giving you full control. Below code assumes `int` is enough range for your integers, but could be expanded to work for most of the range of `int64_t` (but better test the boundary cases to get it fully correct):

```
QJsonValue res = root_object.value("res");

int result = 0;
double tmp = res.toDouble();
if (tmp >= std::numeric_limits<int>::min() && // value is not too small
    tmp <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max() && // value is not too big
    std::floor(tmp) == tmp // value does not have decimals, if it's not ok
   ) {
    result = std::floor(tmp); // let's be specific about rounding, if decimals are ok
} else {
    // error handling if you are not fine with 0 as default  value
}
```

---

A shorter way using `QVariant`, and as an example also getting result into a larger integer type, if you just want to let Qt do it's thing. I'm not sure how it it handles integer values which are too big for a double to handle accurately, so again if that is important, better test.

```
QJsonValue res = root_object.value("res");

QVariant tmp = res.toVariant();

bool ok = false;
qlonglong result = tmp.toLongLong(&ok);

if (!ok) {
    // error handling if you are not fine with 0 as default value
}
```

or same as error-ignoring one-liner, change integer type as appropriate:

```
qlonglong result = root_object.value("res").toVariant().toLongLong();
```

Answer (score 3):

[int QJsonValue::toInt(int defaultValue = 0) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toInt)

> Converts the value to an int and returns it.
>
> If type() is not Double or the value is not a whole number, the
>   defaultValue will be returned.

```
QByteArray JSettings::read_file(QString path)
{
    QFile file;
    file.setFileName(path);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return QByteArray();

    QByteArray barray = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    return barray;
}

QVariantMap JSettings::to_map(QByteArray json)
{
    QJsonDocument jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
    QVariantMap vmap = jdoc.toVariant().toMap();
    // qDebug() << vmap["res"].toInt();
    return vmap;
}

QJsonObject JSettings::to_object(QByteArray json)
{
    QJsonDocument jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
    QJsonObject obj = jdoc.object();
    // qDebug() << obj["res"].toInt();
    return obj;
}
```

Qt JSON portal: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(some_json_data.toUtf8());
QJsonObject root_object = d.object();
QJsonValue res = root_object.value("res");
int i = res.toString().toInt();
```

this is working, QString to Int